# why jquery dialog is not working for below code?

Tags: jquery

I having idea how to open jquery dialog, but what's wrong with below code, please suggest.

here is fiddle link,

[Fiddle Link......](http://jsfiddle.net/QJkVK/1/)

```
<a href="#" class="dialogLink">Open Dialog</a>

<div id="popId"></div>
```

Comment: You added jQuery libraries? Are you trying to use jQuery UI?

Comment: There is no jQuery or JavaScript of any kind in that code.  Only HTML.

Comment: jquery code is there, check fiddle link

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Check out the documentation.  Looks like you could be doing it more easily. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Comment: @user584018: A Stack Overflow question isn't a scavenger hunt.  Include relevant information in the question itself.

Comment: Check if jQuery librarie is loading first. After jQuery UI. And check if are you including CSS files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have your dialog inside a `load` call?

That's not necessary, and you have not defined `dialogTitle` which will throw an error on initialization.

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dialogLink').live('click', function () {
        $("#popId").dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            title: '', // Set this to an actual variable or string
            minWidth: 800,
            minHeight: 300,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            buttons: {
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the previous answer, you do not need to call the load method
at all.  Instead, you will want to call the .dialog method using the $("#popId") 
selector instead of $(this).

Here is a working example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('.dialogLink').live('click', function () {
    $("#popId").dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        title: "This is my test title",
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 300,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```